# listening comprehension - I didn't think what?

Tags: listening

I'm doing some listening practice.
I hear the sentence to be "I didn't think quill could ...", and I don't understand.
Could you help me listen to it?

https://soundcloud.com/xi-zhang-819295156/i-didnt-think

Comment: ... be affected by anything that I did.

Comment: @mc01, sorry, I was a little lazy when I typed the question. I know the "be affected by anything that I did" (thank you for minding) part. I just didn't know the "quill" part...

Comment: No worries - I didn't understand that either. Figured it was from some movie or show w/a character named "Quill" ... Computerized voices maybe aren't the best option for listening comprehension ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence being spoken is actually:

> I didn't think *Will* could be affected by anything that I did.

The problem is with the pronunciation of the speech synthesis software—there's a slight stutter. You're mistaking *Will* for *quill*.